# TinyMCE showing one additional textarea after specifying selector ( @tinymce/tinymce-react )

Tags: reactjs, tinymce

I have specified a `selector` that points to the `textarea` with `id=editable`.
BUT The editor is being **rendered with an extra textarea.**

```
<div className="input has-content valid required redash-view">

  <textarea id='editable'></textarea>

  <Editor
    initialValue="<p>This is the initial content of the editor</p>"
    init={{
        selector: 'textarea#editable',
        height : "500px",
        plugins: 'link image code',
        toolbar: 'undo redo | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright | code',
        resize: false
    }}
    onChange={this.handleEditorChange}
   />

</div>
```

What can I do to resolve this issue ?

PS: I am using:  `@tinymce/tinymce-react": "^3.2.0"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using the `<Editor>` tag to inject TinyMCE into your page you do not need to add the `<textarea>` as well.  The `<Editor>` tag will handle all of that for you.